# Ruby block printing/displaying issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie. The tutorial I am following says anything entered between blocks will be printed/displayed. However, I have not been able to do it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OzDgi0zqJU

at 3:49, he prints out hello or any word between the block. What am I doing wrong that it does not print out anything I enter between block.

```
<h1>All Posts</h1>

<% @posts.each do |post|  %> 
  Hello or something else 
<% end %>
```

RESULT: ALL POSTS

Comment: You don't have any post in your database I guess (means `@posts` variable has no object). Otherwise, for each post `Hello or something else` will print in the html.

Comment: That was my mistake, to say it should be enclosed within <%= %>. I assumed something else. Thank you.

Comment: What does your actual code contains: 'Hello or ...' OR something else?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, I just wondered why it doesn't print as I am following tutorial step by step( No code yet ). Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any **post** in your database I guess (means `@posts` variable has no object). Otherwise, for each post **Hello or something else** will print in the html.

when you want to print something in `.erb`, you will have to enclose it within `<%= %>` only when you want to show something fetch from the database/from the controller instance variable/from the helper file.

If you loop through like below code then you will get the difference:

```
<% 5.times do |t| %>
  Hello or something else
<% end %>
```

It'll print `Hello or something else` five times in the html.

Let's say, Your **Post** table in database contains some data. SO, we can do that like below:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.title %> # I assumed your post model contains a title attribute
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, @Emu! Much appreciated! Now, I have to learn how to create a post!